# How to run multiple pytests with the same start, using previous results for the next tests?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am quite new to pytest, and to testing frameworks in general.

Please assume something like

```
def test_a(a):
    assert a == 1

def test_ab(a, b):
    assert a == 1
    assert b == 2

def test_abc(a, b, c):
    assert a == 1
    assert b == 2
    assert c == 3

def test_abd(a, b, d):
    assert a == 1
    assert b == 2
    assert d == 4
```

You can see it makes sense to use `test_a` and `test_b` in `test_abc` and in `test_abd`.

Assume some calculations occur in these tests, and I would like to cache the results for future
tests using them.

This actually means the build-up phase of some tests are actual other tests.

Is that possible in pytest? Am I asking the correct question?

If so, what's the best practice?

Comment: "build-up phase" sounds like [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html). If you want to make the same assertions in multiple tests, you can use normal functions and call them from multiple tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to pass data between tests: **Module-scoped fixtures**.

Here's what that *might* look like for your code:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def data():
    a = 11
    b = 22
    c = 33
    d = 44
    yield [a, b, c, d]

def test_a(data):
    assert data[0] == 11
    data[1] = 2222

def test_ab(data):
    assert data[0] == 11
    assert data[1] == 2222

def test_abc(data):
    assert data[0] == 11
    assert data[1] == 2222
    assert data[2] == 33
    data[0] = 1111

def test_abd(data):
    assert data[0] == 1111
    assert data[1] == 2222
    assert data[3] == 44
```

Notice that the tests are changing data before the next test. Since the tests run alphabetically, they will all pass because the data is changed from the original set. For simplicity, I used a single fixture, but you can use as many fixtures as you'd like.

Copy/paste that into a Python file and try running it with `pytest`. It works because the data can be changed and passed between tests.

Comment: thanks. What about parallel runs? This doesn't seem like it can be trusted for that.

Comment: This particular example requires the tests to run in a specific order for all the tests to pass, which is due to when the data is being set and when it is being asserted. But it demonstrates the point that you can pass data between tests.

Comment: If running in parallel, data-passing with module-scoped fixtures will still work, but you still may need to run certain tests in a specific order for assertions to succeed.